# Insert pivot table for a sheet that contains empty rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

How to **insert Pivot table using VBA** for a sheet that has empty rows in it and repetitve headers for each group of rows. when i insert a pivot table, it normally catches the first header with the rows beneath of it and ignore the rest of the sheet.